# Reading file dataword by dataword in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I want to read a file containing ASCII characters (regular text file, for our purposes) in Tcl, and store it in an array word by word (that is, dataword by dataword, 32 bits per dataword) as hex.

An example would be a text file containing:

```
ÿÿÿÿûûûûÿÿÿÿ
```

(In ASCII characters, `ÿ` = FF, `û` = FB)

I would like to parse this into an array, resulting in

```
[["FFFFFFFF"], ["FBFBFBFB"], ["FFFFFFFF"]]
```

How do I achieve this? I can't seem to find the appropriate function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Reading

To get the data in, you use something like:

```
set f [open theFile.txt]
set data [gets $f]
close $f
```

Mind you, for this sort of work I'd consider working with the file as binary data instead:

```
set f [open theFile.bin "rb"]
set data [read $f 12]
close $f
```

### Parsing/Converting

Interpreting the data as hexadecimal sequences (in lower-case) is easy though:

```
binary scan $data H8H8H8 word(1) word(2) word(3)
```

That stores the values into an *associative* array called `word` (with indices `1`, `2` and `3`). If you're wanting something like what you're used to in other languages, you then would convert to a Tcl list like this:

```
set wordList [list $word(1) $word(2) $word(3)]
```

Tcl's list values are genuine first-class values. Associative arrays aren't, but are instead named entities so we can use them in `binary scan`.

### Using

After the above you can look things up in the list with:

```
# *Zero*-based indexing is the rule in Tcl
lindex $wordList 0
```

And iterate over them with:

```
foreach item $wordList { puts $item }
```

### Case-conversion

If you really need upper case hex, apply `string toupper` like this:

```
# Nasty type-shimmering trick!
set wordList [string toupper $wordList]
```

Or in Tcl 8.6, you can do this nicer version:

```
set wordList [lmap item $wordList {string toupper $item}]
```

But I'd *actually* just `string toupper` as I used the value under normal circumstances.

```
puts "[lindex $wordList 0] -> [string toupper [lindex $wordList 0]]"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`scan`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/scan.htm) and [`format`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/format.htm) like below:

```
set asc "ÿÿÿÿûûûûÿÿÿÿ"
set result ""
set bytearray [list]
set count 0

foreach l [split $asc ""] {
    append result [format %x [scan $l %c]] ;# %c for reading character as unicode
                                            # %x for converting into hex
    incr count
    if {$count == 4} {
        set count 0
        lappend bytearray [string toupper $result]
        set result ""
    }
}

puts $bytearray
# => FFFFFFFF FBFBFBFB FFFFFFFF
```